# Can I use an iPhone 4S USB power adapter with an iPhone 5S?

Tags: usb, power, iphone

I have an iPhone 4S, and I am thinking about upgrading to an iPhone 5S.  I know that the iPhone 5S has the new Lightning connector, so I will have to get new cables.  But what about the USB power adapter?  Can I use the iPhone 4S USB power adapter with the iPhone 5S?

I found [an Apple page](https://www.apple.com/power-adapters/) that discusses their iPhone 4S USB power adapter, and they do not mention the iPhone 5S, so I'm not sure if it is compatible with the iPhone 5S:

[image]

Comment: If you purchase a new or refurbished iPhone 5S from Apple, it will come with a charger, Lightning cable, and ear-buds.

Comment: That's one ugly little box of a charger, compared to the UK one… just saying, feel free to delete ;) http://i.imgur.com/BUppeOh.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Apple Store has more information on the [USB Power Adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD810LL/A/apple-5w-usb-power-adapter?fnode=48).  It says it is compatible with all iPhone models, from the original iPhone all the way through the iPhone 6 Plus.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

yes, they are both 5w chargers.